# Using HitTest to remote control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, hittest

I am developing a mobile app to remotely control a WPF UI.
The UI is managed by a third party and that third party can add\remove buttons any time.
I am streaming the UI to the client Windows store app and it is sending the touch coordinates to server. 
Server then use HitTest to get the element on WPF UI and run the action.

It works most of the time, but the filter callback is not getting called some times.
This is a dummy code.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(77, 45);
        // Coordinates received on server comes here
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this,
                                   new HitTestFilterCallback(FilterCallback),
                                   new HitTestResultCallback(ResultCallback),
                                   new PointHitTestParameters(p));
    }
    private HitTestFilterBehavior FilterCallback( DependencyObject target)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(target.GetType());
        if (typeof(Button) == target.GetType())
        {
            Button b = (Button)target;
            Button_Click(b, null);
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
        }
        else
        {
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        }
    }
    private HitTestResultBehavior ResultCallback(HitTestResult result)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result.VisualHit.GetType());
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
    }
```

Comment: The app uses a popup pane to show some controls, after this pane is activated for the first time, it is hidden using visibility property, so every time I hit-test a coordinate, I get the reference to the invisible popup pane which is on the top. I have contacted the developer of the app for a solution.

Comment: Then you should continue the hit test, by returning `Continue` instead of `Stop` from your ResultCallback. Did you at least try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `Continue` from your HitTestResultCallback. Otherwise hit testing won't traverse the complete visual tree, and may stop before it has reached the Button control.

```
private HitTestResultBehavior ResultCallback(HitTestResult result)
{
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

See the [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) article on MSDN for details.